# Suggested edit - unanimously accepted but not applied

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Now, this is strange.  I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666454/send-sms-with-variable-using-cordova-social-share-plugin) and the suggested edit has been [unanimously approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13777737), yet (even if I do a force reload with `Ctrl+F5`) the question does not show my edit.  In other words the edit has not been applied.

What could have happened?

I'm asking it here because I'm confident that my edits are being correctly applied on unix.SE and on sec.SE.  I'm suspecting a bug here on SO (so I tagged the question accordingly).

Comment: Weird. I don't see the edit applied either, and I've never visited that question before.

Comment: It's in your actions but you don't seem to have gotten 2 rep for it. I guess it's some kind of race condition where the OP rejected it at the same time that the last reviewer approved it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - That's a good guess alright: I'm not seeing the "Thanks for your edit, it will be reviewed..." message above the question, so it looks as a rejected one.  The only counter argument I see against is that OP does not have the `Custodian` badge, which he would get by reviewing (and rejecting) the edit.

Comment: I guess the OP edited the question too, so his/her edit was applied, but not shown (no "edited x mins ago" link) because of the grace period.

Comment: @alain But the suggestion was made hours after the original post, which would be well outside the grace period.

Comment: Weird! But next time, please correct the misuse of "i" as well. The word "I" is *always* capitalized in English.

Comment: [The post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39666454/timeline) shows the suggested edit being reviewed, but not applied as well.

Comment: Certainly looks like a race condition occurred, however we'll likely need a developer to confirm this.